# How to get data from linq query using select

Tags: c#, linq

I'm testing a simple LINQ select query and want to get two DateTime values from the table, but I'm doing something wrong here and need to know what I'm doing/thinking wrong?

My query:

```
var test = from x in db.Projects where x.ID == 1 select x;
```

Then I try to get on of the values like this:

```
DateTime Date = test. ?????
```

Here I thought I should get a suggestion from the Intellisense after the dot to pick the value from the column `StartDate` the table, but this isn't working.

Comment: You should get `First()` or `Single()` or `ToList();`, etc. before accessing to test.

Comment: Do you want get many row or one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` is going to be an enumeration (`IEnumerable<>`, `IQueryable<>`, etc... many are applicable) of your `Project` type.  So if, for example, you want the first record, you might do this:

```
DateTime Date = test.First().SomeDateProperty;
```

All of the data returned from your query is in `test`.  It could be zero records, one record, many records, etc.

Comment: OK, I thought it could only be one since I asking for the project with the ID == 1 ?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: Then you may very well have a collection with a single value.  In which case `.First()` or `.Single()` (or their `*OrDefault` equivalents) is likely what you're looking for.  Even if a collection has only one item, it's still a collection.

Answer (score 4):

**If you need multiple matches...**

Are you sure that you have multiple `Project` objects that have the same ID of `1` which your query currently suggests? If that is the case, then your query should return all of the records that meet that constraint via the [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) method :

```
// Get your Projects that meet your criteria
var test = db.Projects.Where(p => p.ID == 1);
```

If you need to access properties from these elements, you could either loop through them explicitly :

```
// Iterate through each match that was found
foreach(var t in test)
{
      // Access your properties here
      DateTime dt = t.YourDateProperty;
}
```

Or you could accomplish this using a [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx) statement to only pull the properties that you need :

```
// This will return a collection of Dates mapped from each element in your collection
var testDates = db.Projects.Where(p => p.ID == 1)
                           .Select(x => x.YourDateProperty);
```

**If you only need a single match...**

If you only need to match a single element within your collection, you might consider using the `First()`, `Single()` or their equivalent `FirstOrDefault()` and `SingleOrDefault()` methods, which will return a single entity that you can use as expected :

```
// This will return the first Project with an ID of 1
var test = db.Project.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == 1);
// If it was successful
if(test != null)
{
     // Then you can safely access it here
     DateTime dt = test.YourDateProperty;
}
```

The only difference between the methods mentioned (normal vs `OrDefault()`) is that the `OrDefault()` methods will return `null` if no matching elements are found, so they generally require a null check as seen above.

Comment: There is only one project that has the ID == 1. Should I write the query in another way then?

Comment: I figured that as `ID`s are generally unique. If that is the case, you'll want to look at the second approach mentioned in my response. This will pull only a single matching element (i.e. a `Project` object) and you'll be able to access it as expected.

Answer (score 0):

this is such as:

```
 var date = test.FirstOrDefault();
 DateTime? Date = date != null ? date.StartDate : null;
```

Comment: `Date` variable type should be `DateTime?` to get null value. :)

Comment: Here, `var date = test.FirstOrDefault();` is exactly as same as `DateTime? Date = date != null ? test.FirstOrDefault().StartDate : null;`

Answer (score 0):

In `test` you will have a collection which matches the condition `x.ID == 1`. You should iterate through that collection and take your needed properties.

---

### **Edit**

I suggest you to use the syntax: 
`var result = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID ==1);`